# Current directory from a DLL invoked from Powershell wrong

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

I have a DLL with a static method which would like to know the current directory.  I load the library

```
c:\temp> add-type -path "..."
```

...and call the method

```
c:\temp> [MyNamespace.MyClass]::MyMethod()
```

but both `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and .`Environment.CurrentDirectory` get the current directory wrong...

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What directory are you getting? Errors or output? Also example code for what your doing? Where does C# come into this? Something isn't adding up to me here

Comment: @AthomSfere, well, curiously, I'm getting the directory of the project when the DLL was compiled!

Comment: @AthomSfere, oh, my DLL is written in c# and the calls I'm making are in c# - maybe that's not relevant but I thought I'd throw it in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two possible "directories" you can have in powershell. One is the current directory of the process, available via `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. The other "directory" is the current location in the current Powershell Provider. This is what you see at the command line and is available via the `get-location` cmdlet. When you use `set-location` (alias cd) you are changing this internal path, not the process's current directory.

If you want some .NET library that uses the process's current directory to get the current location then you need to set it explicitly:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = get-location
```

Powershell has an extensible model allowing varying data sources to be mounted like drives in a file system. The File System is just one of many providers. You can see the other providers via `get-psprovider`. For example, the Registry provider allows the Windows Registry to be navigated like a file system. Another "Function" lets you see all functions via `dir function:`.

Comment: so here's what I don't get Mike, if I kick off my Powershell from a given directory, I would think that is the "current" directory that my DLL will see.  In other words, why would the environment variable have any value other than whatever `get-location` would return anyway?  my second question is, how can I access the "other" directory (the one current in the Powershell provider) from my DLL, and is there any reason I wouldn't want to do that?

Comment: @ekkis Typically, yes, starting powershell in a given directory will make that directory the current one for the powershell process. You haven't described what you've done very clearly so we don't know if you changed paths or executed a script that may have done so.

Comment: @ekkis AFAIK there is no way to get the current powershell context inside the DLL. You can either set the current directory explicitly or expose in the DLL the directory to use either via a parameter or static property.

Comment: This is ridiculous. But maybe this is just my perspective as I'm quite used to the Linux way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If the command in your DLL inherits from `System.Management.Automation.PSCmdLet`, the current PS location is available in `SessionState.Path`.

```cs
public class SomeCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
      string currentDir = this.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path;
    }
}
```

To get to the path without a session reference, this code seems to work. This solution I found after going through code that makes GIT autocomplete in [PS GIT Completions](https://github.com/powercode/PSGitCompletions), specifically [this function here](https://github.com/powercode/PSGitCompletions/blob/c8f8af52163489cb7f86bf302eab3b208f553bb7/Git.cs#L84).

```cs
public class Test
{
  public static IEnumerable<string> GetPath()
  {
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace))
    {
      ps.AddScript("pwd");
      var path = ps.Invoke<PathInfo>();
      return path.Select(p => p.Path);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\some\folder> [Test]::GetPath()
C:\some\folder
```